# Does d3's transitions and animations use requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to figure out if d3's default animations use `requestAnimationFrame` for the callback already or if I need to do it myself. For example, I have defined a custom tween that calls a redraw function repeatedly to animation a transition from one domain to another on a graph (this is in coffeescript):

```
rd = @redraw # a function that takes an argument to redraw the graph
@svg.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .tween "zoom", -> 
      interp = d3.interpolate(current_dom, target_dom)
      (t) -> rd interp(t)
```

In all my other calls to redraw, I schedule it with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
scheduleRedraw: =>
  # Stop a previous request if it hasn't executed yet
  cancelAnimationFrame(@animRequest) if @animRequest       
  @animRequest = requestAnimationFrame => @redraw
```

However, I'm wondering if I need to do the same thing here. I have been looking at the d3 source and see that the only reference to `requestAnimationFrame` is in the [d3 timer class](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/timer.js). Hopefully someone with some more knowledge about d3 can help answer the following questions:

- Is the d3 timer used globally for all d3 animations and transitions?
- Do I need to use `requestAnimationFrame` manually here? If not, is there any case where I'd ever need to use it myself while using d3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [d3's wiki:Transitions:Timer](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#timers)

> If your browser supports it, the timer queue will use
>   requestAnimationFrame for fluid and efficient animation.

Comment: Same link for d3 v4 and up: https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#d3-timer: Internally, it uses requestAnimationFrame for fluid animation (if available), switching to setTimeout for delays longer than 24ms.